# How Number.Nan works in this function?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I think the first condition should be true, Because the argument for parameter x is Number.Nan. And it surely equals with the other Namber.Nan within the first conditional if. But I'm wrong apparently. Why? What is the value of x when it is comparing to Number.NaN?

```js
function clean(x) {
  if (x === Number.NaN) {
    // can never be true
    return null;
  }
  if (isNaN(x)) {
    return 0;
  }
}

console.log(clean(Number.NaN));
// expected output: 0
```

Comment: `Number.Nan` does not equal `Number.NaN` and it never will - it's part of the rich tapestry of javascript :p - just like `NaN !== NaN`

Comment: @Jaromanda The rich tapestry of IEEE floats, really.

Comment: @deceze - true! (unlike NaN === NaN) :p

Comment: That's funny and also logical. Thanks.